# How to insert sweet alert type input into database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sweetalert

I want to insert the inputValue of sweetalert into my database. I have a query to insert:

```
swal("Nice!", "Notes: " + inputValue, "success");
```

But it doesn't work

My code:

```
function show_confirm_delete<?=$data->proposalID?>(){
setTimeout(function () {
swal({
    title: "Yakin ingin me-reject Proposal?",
    text: "Beri alasan kenapa anda mereject proposal ini.",
    type: "input",
    showCancelButton: true,
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    animation: "slide-from-top",
    inputPlaceholder: "Tulis disini"
},
function(inputValue){
    if (inputValue === false) return false;

    if (inputValue === "") {
        swal.showInputError("You need to write something!");
        return false
    }

    swal("Nice!", "Notes: " + inputValue, "success");
    window.location.href = "proses-reject.php?id=<?=$data->proposalID?>";
}); }, 1);}
```

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Note: Java has nothing to do with Javascript.